# Is there a 3D equivalent of a 2D matrix?

Tags: matrices

Just thinking, is there a 3D 'equivalent' of a matrix. I know it's possible to get matrices that only have one row or column (i.e. vectors) thus making there a sort of 1D equivalent, but is there a 3D equivalent of a matrix?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5liqUk0ZTw This is not bad. If you already know some of it, skip to around 8'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#As_multidimensional_arrays).

Comment: As part of my acceptance, I'd like to note that @Pedro Tamaroff posted quite an interesting video done in a user-friendly way, thus he is equally deserving of an accepted answer.